# JQuery error undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a small piece of javascript in one of my components. On my development server it is working properly but when I put it online it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This error comes for the first line:

```
jQuery(".rdbookings_interval_grid").live('click', function() {
```

Maybe someone has a clue for me?

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(".rdbookings_interval_grid").live('click', function() {

    // Get the id of the clicked item:
    var interval = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    // Get the active date:
    var date= jQuery( "#wish_date" ).val();
    var service = jQuery( "#service" ).val();
    // Create AJAX data:
    var data = 'date='+date+'&service='+service+'&interval='+interval;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_rdbookings&controller=jquery&task=bookInterval&format=raw", 
        //POST method is used
        type: "POST",
        //pass the data         
        data: data,
        // data type = json 
        dataType: 'json',    
        //Do not cache the page 
        cache: false,
        //success
        beforeSend: function() {
            jQuery( "#loader_date_picker" ).show();
            jQuery( "#msg" ).hide();
        },                      
        success: function (html) {   

            // We're done, show data
            jQuery( "#loader_date_picker" ).hide();

            if(html.status != 666) {

                // Update Reservations:
                jQuery( '#reservations' ).html(html.msg);
                // Update cart
                updateCart();
                // Update cart
                updateGrid();               

            }else{
                jQuery( "#msg" ).html(html.msg);
                jQuery( "#msg" ).show();
            }

        },

    }); 
});
```

Comment: Try to change `live` to `on` and please let me know if that works. What's the version of jQuery you use?

Comment: `live` was removed from jQuery a couple of years ago. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `live` was removed. Change it to `on`

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` is often encountered when you try to call a method on an object when the method doesn't exist for that object. This is because a Javascript method call is really just a) accessing the property of the object that has the name of the method you want to call and b) assuming the value returned is a function and calling it with whatever arguments you think it needs. If it turns out the value is not a function or is undefined, then you get an error.

As commenters have noted, changing `live` to `on` should solve it (i.e. you have been calling the `live` method of a jQuery object [which doesn't have that method](http://api.jquery.com/live/)), but if it's still happening check the line number associated with the error message. You should also think about your processes to make sure your development environment is always reflective of the version of jQuery (and other libraries) that your code might be deployed with to avoid similar problems in the future.